# Concerns regarding joining as a consultant

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, career-development, india

Currently: Working as a full time employee at good MNC as a software engineer in India

The offer: Working remotely as a consultant at a US based startup. They offer a consultant position because companies with no office in India are not allowed to have remote **employees** (that's what I was told by the employer)
Is this correct?

The Question:

1. My main concern is: is it common working as consultant will it have a negative impact on my overall profile if I look for a job after joining this company?
2. The notice period for either party is just 3 days, again is this normal? This doesn't look safe atleast from where iam coming from
3. No mention of holidays in the offer. Consultants are not entitled to holidays?

Comment: "is it common working as consultant will it have a negative impact on my overall profile if I look for a job after joining this company ?". My answer would be "NO". Is there any reason or example that makes you think it would ?

Comment: An employee gets benefits, severance package... whereas a consultant gets 0 benefits, can be kicked off anytime with no severance pay. Having this scenario in mind moving from a place of high stability and benefits to a place of high stability and benefits  is easier compared to moving from no stability and no benefits to a place with high stability and benefits.. So if a consultant wants a job change to another company as a full time employee would be harder vs a full time employee moving to a other company as a full time employee...

Comment: I think this because when it comes to changing job the new company will always judge you based on your current job role, payment etc....so i wanted to know will I be judged negatively if iam working as a consultant.

Answer (score 3):

> US based startup ... companies with no office in India are not allowed to have remote employees

This is utter, utter, nonsense. It doesn't even make sense.

You know when someone tells you a lie that is so ridiculous it does not even make sense as a sentence? That's what that is.  **Since they are outright idiotic liars, I would just walk away.**

Now, putting that aside,

- So they are offering you to be a "consultant". That is largely meaningless. It would be like saying they want you to be "a professional". I guess what they are saying is they want you to contract, ie, rather than be a salaried employee.

> "is it common working as contractor ...

Yes, extremely common

> will it have a negative impact on my overall profile ...

On the contrary, contractors are seen as excellent, get-it-done, risky, aggressive achievers

> The notice period for either party is just 3 days

Every single time I have ever contracted, the notice period has been zero. Either party can walk away at any minute

> This doesn't look safe

Contracting is **incredibly not safe**.  You can make a LOT of money but it is the very definition of "not safe".

> No mention of holidays in the offer

Contractors get absolutely nothing. Nothing, shoony.

No holidays, no sick days, no benefits, no health insurance, and you have to pay all your own equipment (I pay 10s thousands a year on gear for example) and you have to pay all your own, example, accounting etc (more thousands a year), and there is not a chance you'll book jobs 52 weeks of the year, there are lots of weeks you are not making a paese.

Comment: Of course you get holidays: you don't work on these days and you of course don't invoice anything, and you're done...

Comment: I don't know if its true, but it can absolutely make sense.  They may not be set up as a legal taxable entity capable of having employees in India.  That's common even in the states-  I've worked places that couldn't employ people in all 50 states because they didn't have tax presences in each.  They did do B2B contracting with them though.  They may be bullshitting, but I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand like that.

Comment: Although I would disagree on your opinion of contractors-  contractors are generally seen as bottom of the barrel replacable employees you hire and get rid of as fast as possible.  Contractors are contractors because they aren't worth keeping around full time.  If the employer actually valued them, they'd make a full time offer.

Comment: { Gabe, the reason I dismiss it out of hand is that I personally literally hire, and/or, get hired to find and hire, contractors (including literally in India) all the time for literally startups in the US.  Also (other than me literally personally doing it) this is a completely commonplace thing; most programmers would almost certainly literally know dozens of such folks. }